# spring integration dsl aggregator not releasing the messages

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We are using the below code for aggregation and we have noticed the messages are not being released intermittently to subsequent flow. We enabled the trace log for aggregate package

```
IntegrationFlows
                .from("upstream")
                .log(INFO, g -> "Message Received for Aggregation: "  + g.getPayload())
                .aggregate(aggregatorSpec -> aggregatorSpec.correlationStrategy( m -> 1)
                        .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                        .expireGroupsUponTimeout(true)
                        .groupTimeout(30000)
                        .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true)
                        .releaseStrategy(new TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy(100, 30000)))
                .log(INFO, g -> "Message released:"  + ((ArrayList) g.getPayload()).size())
                .handle(someService)
                .get();
```

This log shows the message never completed by aggregate function

```
2019-02-20 16:53:44,366 UTC INFO  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-4] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler- Message Received for Aggregation: Message1
2019-02-20 16:53:44,366 UTC DEBUG [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-4] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler- org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=Message1, headers={jms headers}]
2019-02-20 16:53:44,366 UTC DEBUG [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-4] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler- Handling message with correlationKey [1]: GenericMessage [payload=Message1, headers={jms headers}]
2019-02-20 16:53:44,367 UTC DEBUG [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-4] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler- Schedule MessageGroup [ SimpleMessageGroup{groupId=1, messages=[GenericMessage [payload=Message1, headers={jms headers}] to 'forceComplete'.
```

This log shows the message was completed by aggregate function

```
2019-02-20 16:58:15,386 UTC INFO  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-3] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler- Message Received for Aggregation: Message2
2019-02-20 16:58:15,386 UTC DEBUG [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-3] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler- org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler#0 received message: GenericMessage [payload=Message2, headers={jms headers}]
2019-02-20 16:58:15,386 UTC DEBUG [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-3] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler- Handling message with correlationKey [1]: GenericMessage [payload=Message2, headers={jms headers}]
2019-02-20 16:58:15,386 UTC DEBUG [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0-3] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler- Schedule MessageGroup [ SimpleMessageGroup{groupId=1, messages=[GenericMessage [payload=Message2, headers={jms headers}] to 'forceComplete'.
2019-02-20 16:58:45,387 UTC DEBUG [task-scheduler-6] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler- Cancel 'forceComplete' scheduling for MessageGroup [ SimpleMessageGroup{groupId=1, messages=[GenericMessage [payload=Message2, headers={jms headers}].
2019-02-20 16:58:45,387 UTC DEBUG [task-scheduler-6] org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler- Completing group with correlationKey [1]
2019-02-20 16:58:45,387 UTC INFO  [task-scheduler-6] org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler- Message released: 1
```

Can you help what is missing in the code

Comment: You have a `30 seconds` window for the `groupTimeout` to let it to be expired ad partially released. You second log really shows us such a 30 seconds behavior, but the first one just doesn't wait so long. I don't see anything suspicious in your config, neither logs to catch the problem. Maybe you can come up with a simple project somewhere on GitHub to let us to play with and possibly reproduce? But, please, make it as simple as possible, without JMS already.

Comment: ok, i waited long enough and sent the second message. we see this behavior in real environments production and QA. With tests i am unable to reproduce. I will share the code once i am able to reproduce. Thanks